# Как в opencv4 снять изображение с вебкамеры c++?

Tags: c++, opencv

У меня есть код, написанный на opencv2, он снимает изображение с вебкамеры, но в opencv4 он не работает, отсутствуют некоторый дефайны, а  так же, как я понял, заголовок cv.h.

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // получаем любую подключённую камеру
    CvCapture* capture = cvCreateCameraCapture(CV_CAP_ANY); //cvCaptureFromCAM( 0 );
    assert( capture );

    //cvSetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640);//1280); 
    //cvSetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480);//960); 

    // узнаем ширину и высоту кадра
    double width = cvGetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
    double height = cvGetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);
    printf("[i] %.0f x %.0f\n", width, height );

    IplImage* frame=0;

    cvNamedWindow("capture", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    printf("[i] press Enter for capture image and Esc for quit!\n\n");

    int counter=0;
    char filename[512];

    while(true){
        // получаем кадр
        frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );

        // показываем
        cvShowImage("capture", frame);
    
        char c = cvWaitKey(33);
        if (c == 27) { // нажата ESC
            break;
        }
        else if(c == 13) { // Enter
            // сохраняем кадр в файл
            sprintf(filename, "Image%d.jpg", counter);
            printf("[i] capture... %s\n", filename);
            cvSaveImage(filename, frame);
            counter++;
        }
    }
    // освобождаем ресурсы
    cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
    cvDestroyWindow("capture");
    return 0;
}
```

Вопрос состоит в том, как снять изображение с веб камеры на opencv4 c++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если Вы работаете на C++, то и используйте C++ интерфейс, а не старый сишный.

```
#include <opencv2/core/utility.hpp>
#include "opencv2/videoio.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"

using namespace cv;  

VideoCapture cap;
Mat frame;
...
cap.open(0);
cap >> frame;
imshow("cadr", frame);
```

Comment: а как из frame получить строку байт(собственно сам кадр) и конвертировать эту строку в jpg?

Comment: [imwrite("1.jpg", frame);](https://docs.opencv.org/master/db/deb/tutorial_display_image.html) Почему документацию не смотрите? В [описании Mat](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.2/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html) есть указатель data  на блок данных, если он понадобится